# NSPredicate for simple fetchRequest

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using Core Data to save previous searches in a SearchBar.  My entity is very simple, it just has the property:

```
previousSearch (NSString)
```

When the user types in the search bar, I want to search the database for my previous search.  I keep getting 0 results though.

Here is the code that retrieves the data from Core Data.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText {
    [self.filteredLastSearches removeAllObjects];

    NSEntityDescription *search = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Search" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:search];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"previousSearch=[c]%@", searchText];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error filtering search: %@", [error description]);
    }

    _filteredLastSearches = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:fetchedObjects];
}
```

fetchedObjects is always empty and I'm not sure why.  I can see in the database that the db actually has the ZPREVIOUSSEARCH with a couple values that I've tried to show while searching, but it's always empty.  Is there something I'm missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u initialized the _managedObjectContext?

Comment: @manujmv Yes the managedObjectContext is initialized.

Comment: did u got values when commenting the predicate?

Comment: @manujmv Well when I set a breakpoint there, I get 2 objects, which are the two Search values currently saved in my db.  Then the app crashes with: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Search length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdb72f40`

Comment: try predicate use like this, @"(previousSearch = %@)"

Comment: @karthika hm, still nothing...

Comment: Does fetch without predicate return anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm not sure if `=` operator work with `[c]`. Try to use `like` instead:

   ```
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"previousSearch like[c] %@", searchText];
   ```
2. Also you may want to search not equal results but results that contains (or begins with) your text. In this case you may use `contains` or `beginswith`.

   ```
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"previousSearch contains[c] %@", searchText];
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"previousSearch beginswith[c] %@", searchText];
   ```